# Solve BVP $y''-3xy'-y=x$, $y(0)=y'(1)=0$ by power series, got differences to numerical solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, power-series, finite-differences

I was trying to solve the ODE $y''-3xy'-y=x$ by series. Well, we have regular points all over it so I thought it would be a nice shot, but I am having some problems finding the solutions.

By proposing a solution of the form $y(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}x^{n}$, we will have $y'(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}(n)x^{n-1}$, and $y''(x)=\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}a_{n}(n)(n-1)x^{n-2}$. Substituting in the ODE:
\begin{equation}
\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}a_{n}(n)(n-1)x^{n-2}-
3x\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}(n)x^{n-1}-
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}x^{n}
=x
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}a_{n}(n)(n-1)x^{n-2}-
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}3a_{n}(n)x^{n}-
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}x^{n}
=x
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}a_{n}(n)(n-1)x^{n-2}-
\sum_{n=3}^{\infty}3a_{n-2}(n-2)x^{n-2}-
\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}a_{n-2}x^{n-2}
=x
\end{equation}
After, I arrange the equation in a more direct form:
\begin{equation}
(2a_{2}-a_{0})+
[(3!)a_{3}-4a_{1}]x+
\sum_{n=4}^{\infty}[a_{n}(n)(n-1)x^{n-2}-3a_{n-2}(n-2)x^{n-2}-a_{n-2}]x^{n-2}
=x
\end{equation}
And I find the resulting system:
\begin{alignat*}{2}
   a_{2} & {}={} &  \frac{a_{0}}{2}       \\
   a_{3} & {}={} &  \frac{(1+4a_{1})}{3!}   \\
   a_{n} & {}={} &  \frac{3n-5}{n(n-1)}a_{n-2} 
\end{alignat*}
Separating for odd, and even terms:

For even $k\geq2$
\begin{equation}
      a_{2k}=\frac{(6k-5)}{(2k)(2k-1)}a_{2k-2}=\frac{\Pi_{j=2}^{k}(6j-5)}{(2k)!}a_{0}
\end{equation}
For odd $k\geq2$:
\begin{equation}
      a_{2k+1}=\frac{(6k-2)}{(2k+1)(2k)}a_{2k-1}=\frac{\Pi_{j=2}^{k}(6j-2)}{(2k+1)!}[1+4a_{1}]
\end{equation}
And then comes the trick. I want to solve it for the conditions: $y(0)=0$ and $y'(1)=0$. The former says all my even terms are zero (Yey!), so I can abandon them, but the latter says I need to satisfy this relation $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_{2k+1}(2k+1)=0$. Well, in this case I need to have $-0.25<a_{1}<0$, otherwise I couldn't make the sum zero.
\begin{equation} 
     \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_{2k+1}(2k+1)=a_{1}+3a_{3}+\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}a_{2k+1}(2k+1)=0
\end{equation}
\begin{equation} 
     a_{1}+\frac{(1+4a_{1})}{2!}+(1+4a_{1})\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}\frac{\Pi_{j=2}^{k}(6j-2)}{(2k)!}=0
\end{equation}
Making $S=\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}\frac{\Pi_{j=2}^{k}(6j-2)}{(2k)!}$, I get that $a_{1}=-\frac{\frac{1}{2}+S}{3+4S}$.

Apparently, I don't know if this is right because I am also solving this same problem using finite differences, and the results are really different one from the other as you can see on the image.

[image: Solution]

Comment: What exactly is your question? Where exactly would you want help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your formulas all check out. Let's try to replicate the numerical results. Simplify by shifting the inhomogeneity to the first coefficient, set $c=4a_1+1$, then $a_1=\frac{c-1}4$ and the series becomes
$$
y(x)=\frac{c-1}4x+c\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{\prod_{j=2}^{k}(6j-2)}{(2k+1)!}x^{2k+1}
\\
y'(x)=\frac{c-1}4+c\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{\prod_{j=2}^{k}(6j-2)}{(2k)!}x^{2k}
$$
First evaluate an approximation for $S=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{\prod_{j=2}^{k}(6j-2)}{(2k)!}$ so that for $y'(1)=0$ one needs
$$
0=\frac{c-1}4+cS\iff c=\frac1{1+4S}
$$

```
k=1
term_k = 1/2
S_k = term_k
while S_k+term_k!=S_k :
    k+=1
    term_k *= (3*k-1)/(k*(2*k-1))
    S_k += term_k
c = 1/(1+4*S_k)
n=k
x = np.linspace(0,1.2,150)
term_k=x**3/6
y = term_k
for k in range(2,n):
    term_k *= x**2*(3*k-1)/(k*(2*k+1))
    y+=term_k
y = (c-1)/4*x+c*y
plt.plot(x,y, lw=3, label="series")
```

For the numerical solution, use the second order approximations of the derivatives and use for expediency the general solver `fsolve`. Encode the equations and boundary conditions, the right via a ghost cell, and then plot everything

```
from scipy.optimize import fsolve

for N in [5,10]:
    x = np.arange(N+2)/N
    dx = 1/N
    def F(y):
        y = np.concatenate([[0],y]) # force BC at x=0
        diffeq = (y[2:]-2*y[1:-1]+y[:-2])-3*x[1:-1]*dx/2*(y[2:]-y[:-2]) - dx**2*(y[1:-1] + x[1:-1])
        bc1 = y[-1]-y[-3]
        return [bc1, *diffeq]

    y = fsolve(F,0*x[1:])
    plt.plot(x[1:],y,'-x', lw=0.5,label=f"N={N}")
plt.legend(); plt.grid(); plt.show()
```

The resulting plot shows that the numerical solution is as close as can be expected to the series solution

[image: plot of numerical and series solutions]

As your series solution plot is the same as above, you must have some error in establishing the system for the numerical solution.

Comment: Ah! So my problem was on the finite difference setup! Thanks for the help, and for providing the code ^^!